# A little jerk movement in the page after expand something in body

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project now, and it has a weird bug which I don't understand. Here is what is happening: if I keep clicking on different products on a page to expand and close, after I keep clicking on 4 or 5, the page seems like it scrolls up or down sometimes with a jerk. This effect can also be viewed in this video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u13hec76kwk1r9e/ghosts%20in%20product%20page.mp4?dl=0 (see at 0:16)

Here is this page: http://protec.bluebeetle.me/html/app/products.php?cat=microphones
And here are the login details:

User : you
Password : awesome

Thank you so much for your help guys.

Comment: please reproduce a test case in a fiddle instead of providing the whole webpage

Comment: @BeNdErR or use a Stack Overflow Snippet, its the document icon with the `</>` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the sliding logos after the main hero slider. I am using jQuery.carouFredSel-plugin for them. Because they had different sized images the height of the parent logo slider container was varying weirdly up and down. Fixing the height of the div inside the logos container fixed the issue.